# Can boost be applied to Lucene fields?

Tags: lucene, exist-db

Given a Lucene index configuration in my `collection.xconf`

```xml
<collection xmlns="http://exist-db.org/collection-config/1.0">
  <index xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <fulltext default="none" attributes="false"/>
    <lucene>
      <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer" id="en"/>
      <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.fr.FrenchAnalyzer" id="fr"/>

      <text qname="tei:title" index="no">
        <field analyzer="en" name="en" if="ancestor-or-self::*/@xml:lang='en'" />
        <field analyzer="fr" name="fr" if="ancestor-or-self::*/@xml:lang='fr'" />
      </text>
      <text qname="tei:div" index="no">
        <field analyzer="en" name="en" if="ancestor-or-self::*/@xml:lang='en'" />
        <field analyzer="fr" name="fr" if="ancestor-or-self::*/@xml:lang='fr'" />
      </text>
    </lucene>
  </index>
</collection>
```

How do I boost the hits in `tei:title` elements?

I tried

```xml
      <text qname="tei:title" index="no" boost="2">
        <field analyzer="en" name="en" if="ancestor-or-self::*/@xml:lang='en'" />
        <field analyzer="fr" name="fr" if="ancestor-or-self::*/@xml:lang='fr'" />
      </text>
```

and also

```xml
      <text qname="tei:title" index="no">
        <field boost="2" analyzer="en" name="en" if="ancestor-or-self::*/@xml:lang='en'" />
        <field boost="2" analyzer="fr" name="fr" if="ancestor-or-self::*/@xml:lang='fr'" />
      </text>
```

But while the former just got ignored due to the fact that only the fields are indexed, the latter does not even appear to be valid.

Comment: Is this XML for Lucene or Solr?  While Lucene is used under the hood by Solr, I don't believe Lucene itself is configurable via XML like this.  I think XML configurability is functionality that Solr adds.

Comment: This question is about the Lucene search engine embedded in the eXist database.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is not yet possible, but might be added in the future.

Here is the feature request to track progress: https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/issues/3874